# Initializer lists and assignment overloading (operator =)

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, initializer-list

Does the overloading of the assignment operator propagate to an initializer list?

For example, suppose a class:

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        std::string m_myString; //std::string overloads operator =
    public:
        MyClass(std::string myString);
}
```

And a constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
 : m_myString(myString)
{
}
```

Will the initializer list work out the assignment operator overload on `std::string`? And if not, is there a workaround?

Particularly for GCC.

Comment: What do assignment operators have to do with anything? An object can only be initialized through a constructor; if an assignment operator is invoked it's only because you already have an object instance.

Comment: @ildjarn Honestly, I'm new to initializer lists. My rationale was that since it would replace `m_myString = myString;` in the body of the constructor (an assignment), then there is an assignment *of sorts* in an initializer list.

Comment: That's because if you omitted `m_myString(myString)` from the constructor initialization list, there would implicitly be `m_myString()` (because `std::string` has a non-trivial constructor), so you would still be assigning to a default-constructed object. :-]

Comment: Implicitly? Wow! So in the end it is still an assignment, right?

Comment: In the end, `m_myString = myString;` in the body of the constructor would be an assignment regardless of whether or not `m_myString` appears in the constructor initialization list, yes.

Comment: I assume `myString` is of type `std::string`? You forgot to give it a type.

Comment: You're missing a fundamental part of C++, the difference between `assignment` and `intialization`. *Initializer* lists do initialization not assignment.

Comment: @ildjarn Ok, let's return to the initializer list. If `myString` is in it, it is an assignment at that point, correct?

Comment: @Jesse I think you're onto something. It was fuzzy, but now I see I'm not grasping the distinction.

Comment: "*If `myString` is in it, it is an assignment at that point, correct?*" No, it's initialization, hence the term 'constructor initialization list', and as mentioned in the first comment, an object can only be initialized through a constructor.

Comment: @ildjarn At that point I thought you were referring to `MyClass`, not `m_myString`. So Irit Katriel is correct, it's a copy constructor...

Comment: In this case, yes, it's a copy constructor; in _real_ code, however, you would want to invoke the move constructor, not the copy constructor (assuming you're using C++11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the difference between `assignment` and `initialization`.

Lets look at a simple example with a fundamental type:

```
int a = 10; // Initialization
a = 1; // Assignment
```

The above example is simple and not difficult to understand. However, when you get into user-defined types, it is not as simple because objects are *constructed*.

For example, lets look at `std::string`

```
std::string s1("String1"); // Initialization (constructs s1 using constructor)
std::string s2 = s1; // Initialization (constructs s2 using copy constructor)
std::string s3(s2); // Initialization (constructs s3 using copy constructor)

s1 = s2; // Assigns s2 to s1 using assignment operator
```

The key thing here is `operator=` means different things in different contexts. It all depends on what is on the **left hand side**.

```
  std::string s1 = "Hello"; // Lhs has std::string s1, so this is initialization
  s1 = "Bob"; // Lhs has only s1, so this is assignment
```

And initializer lists  do initialization only (hence the name *initializer* list).

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
 : m_myString(myString) // Initialization
{
}
```

Just be aware, when you call `operator=` in the body of the constructor, you are now doing assignment and not initialization.

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
{
    // m_myString(myString); <-- Error: trying to call like a function
    m_myString = myString; // Okay, but this is assignment not initialization
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it will use the copy constructor rather than the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
 : m_myString(myString)
{
}
```

Note that you have two copies here: one to initialize the parameter `myString`, and one to initialize the member `m_myString`. You don't want that. In C++03, you would take the parameter by const reference:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& myString)
 : m_myString(myString)
{
}
```

And in C++11, you would take the parameter by value and then manually move it into the member:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
 : m_myString(std::move(myString))
{
}
```