# How would I use initializer list to directy create my linked list?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, constructor, initialization

I wrote a templated linked list under the name space `mylib`.

Now what I would like to do is this:

```
mylib::list<int> x = {2,3,4,5}
```

what I would like to do is create a constructor or overload assignment operator to do write above code. I read here [Initializer list for dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124899/initializer-list-for-dynamic-arrays) and [overloading assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369529/initializer-lists-and-assignment-overloading-operator)

I cannot possibly think a way of how to this.

Comment: what is the problem? maybe start by writing some code and let us know what errors you encounter

Comment: @user463035818 The problem was I had no idea how it could be done.

Comment: @user463035818 For my money, the OP said exactly what his problem was, and felt (quite rightly, as it turned out) that he could get an answer here.  He also did some research before posting, what's not to like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what I would like to do is create a constructor or overload assignment
>   operator to do this. ?

You can achieve it by creating a [std::initializer_list constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

```
list(std::initializer_list<int> arr)  // initializer list constructor
{
   for(const auto& it: arr) 
       head.insertElement(it);
}
```

where `insertElement()` is the method you defined to insert elements into your `list` class.

See a [LIVE DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/uU7Wjj)

Comment: Terribly sorry about deleting your live demo, I didn't mean to.  It seems to be a case of 'the dog ate my homework'. I have now put it back in - my original edit was just to correct a couple of typos